# Raspberry Pi is freezing since CPU usage reaches 100 while installing ROS

Tags: makefile, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, ros

I am trying to install ROS on Raspberry Pi 3 (Raspbian Jessie).

After invoking following command, I realized that Raspberry Pi is freezing and it is not responding anymore-

```
sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/indigo
```

I tried to power it off and re-run the above command. However, it got stuck again on the same line. I also tried to use CLI but got in vain. Please see below a picture-

[image]

Please see below the output of `top` command-

[image]

**Any workaround, please? I want to use ROS Indigo on Raspberry Pi.**

Comment: Is your system running out of RAM? Open another terminal and check with `htop` if your system tries to swap. What Pi do you have?

Comment: In GUI mode, there is no application running other then terminal. I am using Raspberry Pi 3 (Raspbian Jessie).

Comment: @Tik0: Please see a picture [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wynqp179qe7rcpe/freeze.jpg?dl=0) showing the output of `top` command. Notice the CPU usage (at the top right corner) is 100%

Comment: Jap, you are running out of memory. I've just added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system is running out of memory. Even your swap is full. You can solve this issue in multiple ways:

1. Use less jobs to build your application by adding the option `--jobs 1` as explained [here](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/verbs/catkin_build.html)
2. Close other memory hungry applications during your build process
3. Increase the swap partition like [so](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-create-or-increase-swap-space-in-linux)

Comment: Indeed. I realized that swap is full. Thanks a lot. Your suggestions worked well.